# Java: Abstract Class Invocation via Main Method

Tags: java, abstract-class

Okay, people are probably going to run to flag this as a duplicate, just by reading the title and without really reading the question. So please know that I HAVE tried to look at other questions on this platform, but have not found something that clears my doubts exactly. Kindly allow me to reach out and ask my question. Thanks in advance.

> Interface is absolutely abstract and cannot be instantiated; A Java abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists.

I do not completely understand the latter part of the statement. Is this talking about the main method being directly within the abstract class itself ? Is it talking about invoking the abstract class via a child's main method ? Or both ?

Secondly, I have seen examples like the following.

```
abstract class Printer
{
     public void print() { … };
}

public class TestPrinter
{
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
          // use of anonymous class
          final Printer p = new Printer()
          {
               @override
               public void print()
               {
                    ...
               }
          }
     }
}
```

And have been told that an anonymous class is at work. But, I seriously do not understand how, since the variable 'p' is clearly being assigned to... and it's an abstract class variable!! How is that even possible? I thought abstract classes can not be instantiated or initialized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The line `final Printer p = new Printer()` refers to a new class which is a subclass of the abstract class, and most importantly overrides the method `print()`.

Comment: @AbhishekVasisht Thanks for the answer. Actually, that much I understand. I know that the "new class" is an anonymous class that everyone is talking about. However, how can an anonymous class be assigned to 'final Printer p' like that? Isn't Printer abstract? And if so, didn't people say that abstract classes can't be instantiated?

Comment: The answer to your question is here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1 Namely, "The class being instantiated is the anonymous subclass."

Comment: @doogabides Thanks for that. I will check it out straight away.

Comment: Okay I think I realised one thing at least. I had, without realising, confused initialisation with instantiation. In the example above, instantiation is not taking place, since an anonymous class is being created that provides all the appropriate implementation details. After that, this anonymous class is being assigned to the abstract class variable in a show of polymorphism. Is this also a form of upcasting ?

Comment: No, instantiation *is* in fact taking place - of a subclass (which is nameless) of your `abstract` class `Printer`. Imagine it to be a named subclass like `SomePrinter extends Printer` and then you create an instance like `Printer p = new SomePrinter();`. It is exactly the same, just a little difficult to imagine because of the anonymity. Go through the  java docs suggested in a comment above

Comment: @kaykay With all due respect, I disagree with your answer. The abstract class is NOT being instantiated. It's the anonymous class which is being instantiated in this example... and the anonymous class is NOT an abstract class. It is a regular class.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, if you read my response carefully. You concluded in your previous comment that instantiation was not taking place. I corrected you saying that instantiation *is* taking place - of a subclass.

Comment: @kaykay You're right. We are going around the same house in different directions. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 final Printer p = new Printer()
      {
           @override
           public void print()
           {
                ...
           }
      }
```

This means that an anonymous class is created which `extends Printer`and the variable `p` is referring to subclass instance.

This is simply **polymorphism** in action. By creating anonymous class here, you are creating a subclass of `Printer` and **using polymorphism you are using the superclass reference variable `p` to refer to object of subclass** which is anonymous but extends Printer because of the syntax below

```
Printer p = new Printer(){...}
```

and this is not only limited to abstract class, you can also create an anonymous class which implements and interface. Consider below example.

```
package com.test;

public interface SomeInterface {

    public void SomeMethod();

}
```

and a class below
package com.test;

```
public class TestAnonymous {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeInterface obj = new SomeInterface() {

            @Override
            public void SomeMethod() {

                System.out
                        .println("Yaayy!!! Creating an anonymous class which implements SomeInterface ");

            }
        };

        obj.SomeMethod();

    }

}
```

which prints out

> Yaayy!!! Creating an anonymous class which implements SomeInterface

What is means that the syntax creates an anonymous class which either extends the abstract class or implements the interface of which reference variable is used to instantiate. It calls method of the subclass.

You can refer jsl.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1

Now your question

> Interface is absolutely abstract and cannot be instantiated; A Java abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists

What I understand from your questions is whether you want to know whether main method can be run in abstract class without instantiating it, The answer is YES

```
package com.test;

public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("main method in abstract class");

    }

}
```

compile and invoke it using `java AbstractClass` and it should print

```
main method in abstract class
```

IF you want to know whether the abstract  class constructor is invoked when instantiating the anynomous class or not, then also the answer is YES. 
Whenver a subclass constructor is called, it invokes super class constructor by making a `super()` call. So abstract class constructor will also get called. 
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/

Comment: Thanks, it's comprehensive. However, my next question would be... if you can do this to both abstract and interface then why does the original statement single the abstract class? I presume it's talking about how BOTH interfaces and abstract classes can NOT be instantiated, but the abstract class CAN have an internal main method and also be invoked by it. Is this true? If so, would you also be kind enough to provide me such an example? Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Prasad. I have already "selected" your answer, but can you also give a real world example. I am finding it difficult to know where this could be applicable properly... as in, why would I ever need to have a main method within an anstract class?

Comment: I think there will be main method used anywhere in real world applications nowadays with every application being on web. Personally I never had to create it.

Answer (score 1):

An `abstract` class is just like any other class - except for the fact that it cannot be instantiated directly. I presume you know the use for such a facility. Hence it can very well have a `main()`, which is a `static` method, not an instance method

The anonymous class in your example, `extend`s the abstract class (or `implement`s an interface, if one is specified). So `p` is not assigned to an `abstract` class instance, but to an instance of a class which extends the abstract class

Answer (score 0):

> A Java abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists.

Since `main()` method is static an can be invoked without instantiation. e.g.

```
abstract class AbstractClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

The same was not true for `interface` till Java7, With Java8 you can have static main method inside `interface` hence same would be true for Java8

You second question, while creating an instance of `Printer` you have defined the sub-class of `Printer` as well but you can not use this defined implementation of `Printer` again(since there is no name associated with the implementation), Hence, its anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

> > A Java abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists.

It is nonsense. Any static method of an abstract class can be invoked. Not just `main().`

> Secondly, I have seen examples like the following ... and have been told that an anonymous class is at work.

That is correct.

> But, I seriously do not understand how, since the variable 'p' is clearly being assigned to... and it's an abstract class variable!! How is that even possible? I thought abstract classes can not be instantiated or initialized.

It is the *anonymous* class that is being instantiated here, which *extends* the abstract class, and provides an implementation of the abstract method. The *reference* to that class is being stored into `Person p`, because `Person` is a superclass of the anonymous class. You can do that for any other class or interface. There's nothing new here.

Comment: Thank you for that EJP. Your explanation is precise. I wish I could have selected more than one answer, but I can't and I am afraid that I will have to "select" the one who answered in a similar manner before you. Thanks nonetheless. It's appreciated.